# Add python project based on pyproject.toml to yocto image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm putting together a recipe that's supposed to add `amqtt` to my image (https://github.com/Yakifo/amqtt). The project only comes with a `pyproject.toml` but lacks a `setup.py`. Thus, `bitbake` is complaining that `setup.py` cannot be found I'm on branch `dunfell` and these are the most relevant parts of my recipe:

```
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/Yakifo/amqtt"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/Yakifo/amqtt;protocol=https"

SRCREV = "4beb912c2a0d58d66140ce68b6a31991c2c48b30"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit setuptools3 pypi distutils
```

Your input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution by adding a `do_configure:prepend()` function worked for me, with one exception.

If you're going to have more than one recipe with this workaround, they will conflict in the site-packages directory, since setup() doesn't know what to call them.

I'd recommend populating at least some of the arguments to the setup() function. Your recipe already has PYPI_PACKAGE, LICENSE and PV defined, so they're easy to add.

```
do_configure:prepend() {
cat > ${S}/setup.py <<-EOF
from setuptools import setup

setup(
       name="${PYPI_PACKAGE}",
       version="${PV}",
       license="${LICENSE}",
)
EOF
}
```

Comment: This answer should be followed.  If you don't supply the arguments to the setup() function and you use this trick on multiple recipes, you'll get a very hard to debug conflict because the installed wheels will have the same name including UNKNOWNs instead of the real values.

Answer (score 1):

As of Yocto Release 4.0 (Kirkstone), installation of Python packages using Poetry is supported via the `python_poetry_core` class - [Release 4.0 Migration Guide - Python Changes](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/migration-guides/migration-4.0.html?highlight=migration)

My particular scenario (using Gatesgarth 3.2.3) doesn't really justify the effort in updating to Kirkstone. Just changing the packaging system is not an option (it's not my package I'm trying to install).

My workaround: I've opted to simply use Poetry (1.2.1, the latest at time of writing) to manually build the `.tar.gz`. It turns out that Poetry generates a `setup.py` with the info contained in `pyproject.toml`. I commit that package archive to my Yocto project repo, and override `SRC_URI` in the appropriate recipe to use it instead of the version from PyPi.

Note that I did have some issues in getting `poetry build` to run due to TOML format difference between the version that it was written for (which I was unable to zero in on) and the latest. I had to modify the `pyproject.toml` a bit because of this.

Answer (score 1):

If the `pyproject.toml` file is composed in a way that it can be used with `setuptools` then just creating simple `setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup()
```

by adding the following to the bitbake recipe fixes the problem:

```
do_configure:prepend() {
cat > ${S}/setup.py <<-EOF
from setuptools import setup

setup()
EOF
}
```

More details [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html)

My full bitbake recipe `python3-leapseconddata_2.0.0.bb`:

```
HOMEPAGE = "https://pypi.org/project/leapseconddata/"
SUMMARY = "Python Leap Second List."
LICENSE = "GPLv3"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSES/GPL-3.0-only.txt;md5=8da5784ab1c72e63ac74971f88658166"

PYPI_PACKAGE = "leapseconddata"

SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "c72d40f56bf7a1a98ee0c0c12ea2fca76a38a5cb7239f8e182f13e639436992d"

inherit pypi setuptools3

do_configure:prepend() {
cat > ${S}/setup.py <<-EOF
from setuptools import setup

setup()
EOF
}
```