# Yocto Kirkstone Bitbake Recipe using Python3 TOML for python3-fastapi

Tags: python-3.x, pip, yocto, yocto-recipe, toml

I am using Yocto Kirkstone to build a target rootfs for Linux 5.15 on a 64-bit arm device.

I want to use the python3 module "nicegui" as a UI for this device. There was no existing receipe for it so I added one ( shown below ). This library depends on 'fastapi', which in turn depends on 'typing-extensions'. Neither have recipes for Yocto and so I attempted to add those. Unfortunately, they depend on the TOML installation configuration file, instead of the tranditional setup.py method that Yocto can handle natively. Although the following attempts for recipes for these modules complete successfully, but do not actually create the source files that can be imported on the device.

I have tried all suggestions from both of these related posts (neither work):
[Add PyPi package for Yocto without setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76941439/add-pypi-package-for-yocto-without-setup-py)
[Add python project based on pyproject.toml to yocto image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889804/add-python-project-based-on-pyproject-toml-to-yocto-image?noredirect=1&lq=1)

How can I write a Yocto Kirkstone recipe to successfully insteall python3-fastapi and python3-typing-extensions? Thanks.

Please note that I have tried the following for fastapi and typing-extensions as well:

```
do_configure:prepend() {
cat > ${S}/setup.py <<-EOF
from setuptools import setup

setup(
       name="${PYPI_PACKAGE}",
       version="${PV}",
       license="${LICENSE}",
)
EOF
}
```

NiceGUI:

```
SUMMARY = "Recipe to embedded the Python PiP Package nicegui"
HOMEPAGE ="https://pypi.org/project/nicegui"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=dbc3e3da2b6b1b24fcf4e94e809c1257"

inherit pypi setuptools3
PYPI_PACKAGE = "nicegui"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "8752807e3a9ade2e56f63c3ba9b36b48"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "137601729eddc721346193089c8ead290f8dcdfd9664de2cfaaaab72ece5feb8"
```

FastAPI:

```
SUMMARY = "Recipe to embedded the Python PiP Package fastapi"
HOMEPAGE ="https://pypi.org/project/fastapi"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=95792ff3fe8e11aa49ceb247e66e4810"

inherit pypi python_poetry_core
PYPI_PACKAGE = "fastapi"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "5e9226e70e1553a630599cf584ed53de"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "266775f0dcc95af9d3ef39bad55cff525329a931d5fd51930aadd4f428bf7ff3"
```

typing-extensions:

```
SUMMARY = "Recipe to embedded the Python PiP Package typing_extensions"
HOMEPAGE ="https://pypi.org/project/typing_extensions"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=64fc2b30b67d0a8423c250e0386ed72f"

inherit pypi python_poetry_core
PYPI_PACKAGE = "typing_extensions"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "3cd9b7b9a465afbcca8548e11668ca64"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "1a9462dcc3347a79b1f1c0271fbe79e844580bb598bafa1ed208b94da3cdcd42"
```